# Log Base 2 Prolog

Tags: logging, prolog

I am making a log base 2 only calculator using prolog
my code is simple here it is:

```
logBase2(1,0). 
logBase2(N,R) :-
                N1 is N/2,
                logBase2(N1,R1),
                R is R1 +1.
```

the problem is that it gives an out of local stack error for square number when I try another solution instead of giving a false, and it gives the same error for not square numbers. any suggestions ? much appreciated.

Comment: Your base case use requires unifying am integer with a float...

Comment: Just in case anybody else gets to this question looking for base 2 logarithm of a number N, you can use builtin log function  `Log is log(N)/log(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
logBase2(1,0). 
logBase2(N,R) :-
                N>1,
                N1 is N//2,
                logBase2(N1,R1),
                R is R1 +1.
```

to all who want the answer, it was a simple check before the loop.